# Access controller instance from Application class function

Tags: javascript, function, ember.js, controller

It's possible in EmberJs access a controller instance from an application class function?

My app is part of a registration page. When user clicks on save button i have to extract data from app controller and send it to a js save function for the whole page.

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you mean by *application class function*?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the button that triggers the action inside your Ember app, and then call out of them Ember app into a function that's declared in a different scope on your page.